# Infinite scroll and sorting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using the following JavaScript to do an infinite scroll and sorting:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    if (!busy) {
      busy = true;
      $('#spinner').show();
      // AJAX call and append list
      $('#spinner').hide();
      busy = false;
    }
  }
}); 
$('#sort').on('change', function () {
  // AJAX call and replace list
});
```

But the problem I'm having, is when sorting the scroll function is also fired, which results in 2 AJAX calls and adding more results to the list than expected.

How do I prevent the scroll function from firing when doing a sort on my list?

**Update**

A simple example. First scroll down, then do a sort which will result in two alerts.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bsLg7jaw/13/)

Comment: Can you provide working example?

Comment: `$('#sort').on('change', function () { busy=true

                 //Ajax call and replace list
busy=false;
            });`

Comment: No @mplungjan, I already tried that... Thanks

Comment: @Justinas, updated with a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't create all these random jquery objects. Create once, then  reuse. Best way is by putting it into a scope so other code isn't disturbed by the local variables.

```
+function($window, $document, $) {
   ... code here
}(jQuery(window), jQuery(document), jQuery)
```

Then to your issue. You need to block your firing state for an update until the other is done. You have the busy variable, I renamed it to loading.

The problem is that loading gets set to true at the end of sort. Afterwards the scroll event is triggered by the javascript thread through the resizing of the the content whatnot. This event vinds the loading to be done, thus retriggering the load next.

What you need is a second variable that defines that the scroll was likely triggered by the sort update.
I used `triggeredByResort` for that. It's a variable that auto resets to false after 150 milliseconds, but if a 'scroll' event happens within that timeframe the first occurance of scroll is terminated. A second occurance will happen. If nothing happens the variable will auto reset to false after 150 milliseconds ish.

```
+function(window, document, $) {
   var $spinner = $('#spinner');
   var $sort = $('#sort');
   var $window = $(window);
   var $document = $(document);
   var triggeredByResort = false;
   var loading = false;
   var doneLoading = function() {
       $spinner.hide();
       loading = false;
   }
   var startLoading = function() {
      loading = true;
      $spinner.show();
   }
   $sort.on('change', function() { 
        var direction = $sort.val();
        startLoading();
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'sortstufftarget.html',
                   data: {
                      direction: direction,
                      // stuff data
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                      triggeredByResort = true;
                      window.setTimeout(function() {
                          triggeredByResort = false;
                      }, 150);
                      // replace stuff code here

                      doneLoading();
                   },
                   error: function(data) {
                      window.alert('an error occured');
                      doneLoading();
                   }
               });
   });

   $window.scroll(function () {
       if (!loading && $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() == $document.height()) {
                if(triggeredByResort) {
                   triggeredByResort = false;
                   return;
                }
                startLoading();
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'loadnewstufftarget.html',
                   data: {
                      // load new stuff data
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                      // append stuff code here
                      doneLoading();
                   },
                   error: function(data) {
                      window.alert('an error occured');
                      doneLoading();
                   }
               });
            }
        }); 
}(window, document, jQuery)
```

Comment: The delayed triggeredByResort variable did the trick. Good answer. Thanks